# Passing arguments to javascript function

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
>   [javascript variable scope/closure in loop after timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029021/javascript-variable-scope-closure-in-loop-after-timeout)

Can you please explain step by step why the results are different?

**Snippet A** (alerts 10)

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) if(i==3) setTimeout(function() {alert(i);}, 100);
```

**Snippet B** (alerts 3)

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) if(i==3) setTimeout((function(p) {
   return function() {alert(p);}
} )(i), 100);
```

Comment: This basic issue has been the subject of hundreds of questions here. The answer is simple: the `i` referenced in the timeout handler is the `i` from the outer scope, and it's being changed by the loop.  That is, there is only one `i` involved.

Comment: @Pointy Find a duplicate and flag it then.

Comment: Basically start typing in a question with the words "javascript", "loop", and "timeout" or "handler".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable's scope is either the global scope (`window` in a browser) or a function.

In the first case `i` is defined in the scope containing the `for` loop. This is why it still changes until the end of the loop before the callback given to `setTimeout` is executed.

In the second case, the intermediate function contains and keeps another variable, `p`. Note that this would have worked without the test, as this would have been a different closure for each `setTimeout`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I suppose the argument is always passed by reference, right?

Comment: No, they're always passed by value but i isn't passed, in the first case, until the alert is called. At this time the loop has ended. But be careful with "passed by value vs passed by reference" : it's clear for a primitive type but the value of a variable can be a reference to an object.